# MySQL AND condition parenthesis not working

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, parentheses, operator-precedence

The following select statement does not return the correct results, despite furiously moving parenthesis around:

`SELECT * FROM Table A where (refId != <some refId> and date <= (now() - INTERVAL 10 DAY))`

It seems that the AND condition is short circuiting for some reason, meaning that if the `refId` does in fact equal the `refId` in question, the date doesn't matter. This statement needs to return rows without the `refId` in question but only if the `date` condition matches as well.

For instance, I have many `refIds`, but I want to filter out one of them, but only when the `date` is also outside the 10 day window.

```
Sample Data:                                 Expected Results:
-----------                                  -----------------
|id|refId|   date   |       refId != 5 AND date <= (now() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
|1 | 1   | 2018-2-10|               Only row 1 should be returned since the
|2 | 5   | 2018-2-14|              refId !=5 AND the date is <= 10 days ago.
|3 | 2   | 2018-2-20|
|4 | 5   | 2018-2-22|
|5 | 5   | 2018-2-12|
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Are you sure about excepted output? 20.02.2018 is after than 13.02.2018 (23.02.2018 - 10 days). row 1 fits to your condition more.

Comment: Correct. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `=` and `or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A
WHERE (refId = <some refId> OR date <= (now() - INTERVAL 10 DAY))
```

Comment: `or` will not work, There are many `refIds`, I want to return rows with all but ONE `refId` where the date is also outside the 10 day window. if I test each condition separately, they work fine, but I need the condition to only work if both conditions are met. Currently, if a row contains the `refId` i'm trying to filter out, it seems to not even check the second condition.